# Hovering <tr> effects other <tr>s in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I´ve made a table with a basic informations and every odd and even row has different color. On `:hover` effect it is orange, regardless if it is even or odd.

But when I wanted to "group" 3 `<tr>` I found out a problem. I tried to wrap it into `<div>` but it didn´t work. My goal is: when you hover 1 of the 3 rows it applies the hover effect on all of them. I´ve managed to apply hover effect on all of the rows but only if you hover the first one because it is the adjacent sibling and general sibling selector. Is there any way how to make it in reverse?

[Look at the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandik70/7ybud8x6/4/)

If you hover the second or third row at the third row (In total fourth and fifth row) you will more clearly what I´ve tried to describe.

Thanks for anwers.

```css
.vyjimka {
  background-color: rgba(237, 234, 235, 0.2)!important;
}

.vyjimka:hover {
  background-color: #ffa768!important;
}

#SlouceneBunky:hover+.vyjimka {
  background-color: #ffa768!important;
}

#SlouceneBunky:hover~.vyjimka2 {
  background-color: #ffa768!important;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background-color: #ffa768;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(237, 234, 235, 0.2);
}

tr:nth-child(even):hover {
  background-color: #ffa768;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Služba</th>
    <th>Popis</th>
    <th>Cena</th>
    <th>Platba</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Text 1 </td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Text 1 </td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="SlouceneBunky">
    <td rowspan="3">Something</td>
    <td>Text 1 </td>
    <td>Text 2 </td>
    <td rowspan="3">Text 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="vyjimka">
    <td>Text 1 </td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="vyjimka2">
    <td>Text 1 </td>
    <td>Text 2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group table rows with the `<tbody>` tag:

```css
tbody:hover tr {
  background-color: #ffa768;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(237, 234, 235, 0.2);
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Služba</th>
      <th>Popis</th>
      <th>Cena</th>
      <th>Platba</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Text 1 </td>
      <td>Text 2</td>
      <td>Text 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Text 1 </td>
      <td>Text 2</td>
      <td>Text 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="SlouceneBunky">
      <td rowspan="3">Something</td>
      <td>Text 1 </td>
      <td>Text 2 </td>
      <td rowspan="3">Text 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vyjimka">
      <td>Text 1 </td>
      <td>Text 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vyjimka2">
      <td>Text 1 </td>
      <td>Text 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```